# Função Javascript funciona só uma vez

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostaria de uma ajuda com essas funções. Gostaria que a ultima td alterne cada vez que for clicada entre ativo e inativo. Mas só funciona na primeira vez clicada depois não funciona mais. Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue código exemplo abaixo.

Obrigado.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#tabela tbody tr').each(function(i, linha) {
       $(this).find('a[name=botaoAtivo]').click(function() {
          var teste = $(linha).find('td:eq(4)');
          console.log('Teste: ' + teste);
          teste.html("<a name='botaoInativo' href ='#'><span class='badge badge-danger'>Inativo</span></a>");
    });
 $(this).find('a[name=botaoInativo]').click(function() {
   var teste2 = $(linha).find('td:eq(4)');
   console.log('Teste2: ' + teste2);
   teste2.html("<a name= 'botaoAtivo' href ='#'><span class='badge badge-success'>Ativo</span></a>");
         });
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id = "tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Fantasia</th>
      <th>Cidade</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Cliente1</td>
      <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
      <td>exemplo@exemplo.com</td>
      <td><a name= "botaoAtivo" href ="#">Ativo</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cliente2</td>
      <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
      <td>exemplo@exemplo.com.br</td>
      <td><a name="botaoInativo" href ="#">Inativo</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Funcionou Assim Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** com base nos comentários

Neste caso, para seguir da forma que está sendo feita, alteraria o código para:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find('#tabela a[name=botaoExemplo]').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass("ativo")) {
  $(this).removeClass("ativo").addClass("inativo");
  $(this).html("inativo");
}
else {
  $(this).removeClass("inativo").addClass("ativo");
  $(this).html("ativo");
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Fantasia</th>
  <th>Cidade</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Status</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Cliente1</td>
  <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
  <td>exemplo@exemplo.com</td>
  <td><a name="botaoExemplo" href="#" class="ativo">Ativo</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Cliente2</td>
  <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
  <td>exemplo@exemplo.com.br</td>
  <td><a name="botaoExemplo" href="#" class="inativo">Inativo</a></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61ty4sw2/

Resumo das modificações:

- usa o mesmo name em todos os casos, por simplicidade
- utiliza classes para controlar o estado
- altera somente as classes de controle e o texto dentro do link

---

**(original)**

A função funciona uma única vez pq a DOM é analisada no seu document ready. Como vc altera a DOM posteriormente, com o click, a DOM não é reavaliada. Para resolver isso de forma rápida e simples vc pode fazer o botão da seguinte maneira: `<a htef="#" onclick="ativar()">Inativo</a>` e escrever as funções ativar e inativar em um bloco `<script>`.

Comment: Eu já tentei essa forma só que aí altera todos as linhas. Não consigo que altere só a linha clicada

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabela').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    const status = $(this).find('[name]').attr('name')

    if (status == 'botaoAtivo') {
      $(this).find('[name]').attr('name', 'botaoInativo').html('Inativo')
    } else {
      $(this).find('[name]').attr('name', 'botaoAtivo').html('Ativo')
    }
    
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Fantasia</th>
      <th>Cidade</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Cliente1</td>
      <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
      <td>exemplo@exemplo.com</td>
      <td><a name="botaoAtivo" href="#">Ativo</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cliente2</td>
      <td>Santa Cruz do Sul/RS</td>
      <td>exemplo@exemplo.com.br</td>
      <td><a name="botaoInativo" href="#">Inativo</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".alterarEstado").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).find("span").text() === "Ativo") {
      $(this).find("span").text("Inativo");
      $(this).find("span").toggleClass("badge-success badge-danger");
    } else {
      $(this).find("span").text("Ativo");
      $(this).find("span").toggleClass("badge-success badge-danger");
    }
  });
});
```

Alterando o seu botão para algo como:

```
<td>
    <a class="alterarEstado" href="#">
        <span class='badge badge-danger'>Inativo</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Ao invés de usar o atributo `name` utilize uma `class` e registro o evento nesta `class`.

[EXEMPLO](https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/zYxermO?editors=1010)